# Create PHP Array Dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, array-push, array-key

I want to create a PHP array with the following result. The array values will be passed dynamically.

```
array(
    __( 'Bedroom', "my-text-domain" ) => 'Bedroom', 
    __( 'Luxury', "my-text-domain" ) => 'Luxury', 
    __( 'Modern', "my-text-domain" ) => 'Modern', 
)
```

I tried both `arraypush` and `key => value` pair. But the expected output wasn't obtained.

array_push:

```
array_push($categories_dropdown, "__( '" . $cat_name . "',  'my-text-domain'  ) => '" . $cat_name . "'");
```

Array push results,

```
Array
(
    [0] => __( 'Uncategorized',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Uncategorized'
    [1] => __( 'Bedroom',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Bedroom'
    [2] => __( 'Luxury',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Luxury'
    [3] => __( 'Modern',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Modern'
    [4] => __( 'Office',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Office'
    [5] => __( 'Reception',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Reception'
    [6] => __( 'Vintage',  'my-text-domain'  ) => 'Vintage'
)
```

key => value pair :

```
$categories_dropdown["__( '".$cat_name."',  'my-text-domain'  )"] = $cat_name;
```

key => value pair results,

```
Array
(
    [__( 'Uncategorized',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Uncategorized
    [__( 'Bedroom',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Bedroom
    [__( 'Luxury',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Luxury
    [__( 'Modern',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Modern
    [__( 'Office',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Office
    [__( 'Reception',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Reception
    [__( 'Vintage',  'my-text-domain'  )] => Vintage
)
```

How can I result the above mentioned patterned array dynamically in PHP?

Comment: `__()` is a function, why do you enclose it in quotes?

Comment: The array is required to create a custom element in wpBakery plugin and, it's the array pattern that the parameter accepts sir. When hard coding the values it works fine, now I want the values dynamically assigned

Comment: So why not `$categories_dropdown[__( $cat_name,  'my-text-domain'  )] = $cat_name;`?

Comment: @u_mulder it result the following sir, `Array
(
    [Uncategorized] => Uncategorized
    [Bedroom] => Bedroom
    [Luxury] => Luxury
    [Modern] => Modern
    [Office] => Office
    [Reception] => Reception
    [Vintage] => Vintage
)`. It replaces the ` __( 'Bedroom', "my-text-domain" )` with `[Bedroom]` likewise

Comment: Yes, the function `__()` is called. And what do you expect?

Comment: I expect the array value like `__( 'Bedroom', "my-text-domain" ) => 'Bedroom'` , does both result the same?

Comment: `'__( 'Bedroom', "my-text-domain" )'` is a __string__. Why do you need this string instead of result of caliing `__()`?

Comment: @u_mulder You were right. I only considered the structure of the array. But the final outcome worked perfectly. `$categories_dropdown[__( $cat_name, 'my-text-domain' )] = $cat_name;` This lined worked functionally. Make it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"__( '".$cat_name."',  'my-text-domain'  )"` is a string, and you need result of function execution, so remove quotes and call the `__()`  function:

```
$categories_dropdown[__($cat_name, 'my-text-domain')] = $cat_name;
```